# Observing Singleton class with @published properties to map models through a view model

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observable, combine

I have a singleton data manager class with `@Published` high level models. I need to process these through a viewmodel class pass the simplified display models / properties back to the view. For the first time loading this works, but the changes on data manager aren't observed on the SwiftUI View.

```swift
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = DataManaer()

  @Published var modelsA: [ModelA]
}

struct ViewA: View {

  @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    // UI Code Like similar to this
    ForEach(vm.displayModels) {
      ItemView($0)
    }
  }

}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // Few other properties here
  @Published var someState: Bool

  var dataManager = DataManager.shared

  // This is a computed property based on datamanager's models
  var displayModels: [DisplayModel] {

    dataManager.modelsA.compactMap { MapModelAToDisplayModel($0) }
  }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix the above code, so that when DataManager's modelsA or modelsB changes, the computed property from ViewModels would trigger view update?

Comment: Don’t use a computed property, use Combine to subscribe to changes in DataManager and update a published property in ViewModel with the result. Or skip the view model and work directly with DataManager from the view.

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson. Spot on. Issue has been resolved. I referred the answer below as well which is very similar to what you have suggested. (Due to the nature of the beast, I will have to stick with a vm as there is too much business logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. You are using a computed property (meaning it it not @Published)
2. Inside of the computed property, you directly read the values of the published property. You are not listening to that published property. (Meaning: you are only reading the models array of DataManager when the computed property is accessed directly.)

You could use Combine to listen to changes of that published property and then update your own property, which you then mark as @Published. Like so:

```
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var dataManager = DataManager.shared
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    @Published
    var displayModels = [DisplayModel]()

    init() {
        dataManager.$modelsA
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] models in
                self?.displayModels = models.compactMap { MapModelAToDisplayModel($0) }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

That will explicitly listen to changes in `modelsA` of `DataManager` and will then do the mapping when a change got signalled.

There are a few important tidbits hidden in the code:
First of all, you need that one line `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`, because in SwiftUI it's important to only do changes to the UI (that includes @Published properties that influence UI) on the main thread.
Also it is important to have a `[weak self]` reference in the sink. Otherwise you will end up with a retain cycle and leak memory. (ViewModel holds the DataManager, that holds the models publisher, that then holds a reference to the sink, which in turn holds a reference to the ViewModel.) Using `[weak self]` fixes that issue :)

Comment: Thank you @JanMensch for the detailed answer. I did manage to fix the problem with you and Joekim suggested.

Comment: This basically is reimplementing what `View` structs and `body` does already, why not just use those?

Comment: If there is just a simple mapping happening, going through a ViewModel *can* be unnecessary, agreed. However there might still be valid reasons to use the ViewModel approach. For example if there is more complex conversion or result combining going on and you don't want the clutter the view code. Or if you simply don't want to tightly couple the view to the DataManager. Depends on the situation.

Comment: @malhal For simpler logic yes indeed, in my case there are complex business logic that goes into mapping and unit testing requirements. Also the Usecase here is just one thing that's happening on that view. I only extracted the parts necessary to construct this issue I was having problems with. 

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @JanMensch But the `View` struct IS the view model. In Swift logic goes in funcs not classes.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already, so the solution is to remove the `ViewModel` class you made, e.g.

```
struct ModelA: Identifiable {
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
  static let shared = DataManager()
  static let preview = DataManager(previewing: true)

  @Published var modelsA: [ModelA] = []

//  func load()
//  func save()
}

struct ViewA: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var dataManager

  var body: some View {
    // UI Code Like similar to this
    ForEach(dataManager.modelsA) { model in
        ItemView(model)
    }
  }

}
```